# Pictures are not imported

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am having an issue in Magento where my pictures are not being uploaded even though rest of the fields gets properly imported.

I don't know what's the path that I should specify for my pictures in order to get uploaded.

In my feed file I have something like this: /test.png or just test.png and I have tried to copy the image to the \var, \var\import, \var\importexport

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using the default CSV-Import try to put them in `media/import`.